# Having issues with DHCP classes

Tags: dhcp, linux-networking, dhcp-server, isc-dhcp

I'm having issues with DHCP classes matching mac addresses.

We have a lot of one type of machine and I want to get the IPMI cards in the same pool.

I've tried the following;

```
class "IPMI" {
match if (substring(hardware, 0, 3) = 0c:c4:7a);
}
subnet 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 {
option routers 10.0.0.1;

pool {
range 10.0.1.0 10.0.1.255;
allow members of "IPMI";
}
}
```

For some reason nothing is getting matched and the machines aren't picking up reservations.

```
Oct 14 11:32:52 gotti dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from 0c:c4:7a:1c:d4:37 via em1: network LAN: no free leases
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `dhcp-eval(5)`:

```
   hardware

      The  hardware  operator returns a data string whose first element is
      the type of network interface indicated in packet being  considered,
      and  whose subsequent elements are client’s link-layer address.   If
      there is no packet, or if the RFC2131 hlen field  is  invalid,  then
      the  result  is  null.   Hardware types include ethernet (1), token-
```

So you likely either need to add the type of network to the search:

```
match if (substring(hardware, 0, 3) = 01:0c:c4:7a);
```

Or to blindly assume ethernet and start the search not at the first position:

```
match if (substring(hardware, 1, 3) = 0c:c4:7a);
```

In testing, the "type of network" as a leading `1:` or `01:` did not pan out, while the following did:

```
class "FOO" {
  match if substring(hardware, 1, 3) = 08:00:27;
}

subnet 192.168.33.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  option routers 192.168.33.1;

  pool {
    range 192.168.33.110 192.168.33.120;
    allow members of "FOO";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, still don't seem to be having any joy. Nothing peculiar in the logs either.